# WPF, Loaded event, IsLoaded property

Tags: wpf

If I attach a handler to the Loaded event of an element (no matter if it is in the VS designer or in the code), it sets the IsLoaded property to true.

For instance, I have a TabControl with two TabItems. There is a button on each TabItem. The first TabItem is the default item (selected when my window is shown). The Button on the second TabItem has attached the Loaded event. In this case, the button on the first TabItem has IsLoaded set to true and the button on the second TabItem should be set to false but it is set to true.

When I unset the Loaded event it works as expected - the first button has IsLoaded true, the second has false.

Is this a wpf bug or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

See an example.

This code causes the IsLoaded property of btn2 set to True (Note: the btn2_Loaded method is empty).

XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                <Button x:Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click" />
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Tab2">
                <Button x:Name="btn2" Loaded="btn2_Loaded" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.btn2.IsLoaded.ToString());
    }
```

Start the application and just click the btn1.

Now remove the Loaded handler:

```
            <TabItem Header="Tab2">
                <Button x:Name="btn2" />
            </TabItem>
```

Start the application again and click the btn1.

Now the IsLoaded is False! Why is this happening? Attaching an event handler causes loading of the particular element?

Comment: So you would like the loaded event of button2 to only fire when the tab is changed?

Comment: It is not about firing the event. It is about the value of the IsLoaded property. Attaching a handler to the Loaded event of the button2 causes setting of the IsLoaded property of the button2 to true. If you don't attach a handler, it is set correctly to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is neither a bug in WPF nor are you doing something wrong. The MSDN page on [Object Lifetime Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx) says that

> The Loaded event is raised before the final rendering, but after the
>   layout system has calculated all necessary values for rendering.

You can not make any more precise assumption on when exactly Loaded is called. In your case i guess WPF delays loading of the non-visible (i.e. not yet rendered) elements, *unless* a Loaded handler is attached. It is just free to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure if I undestand. I didn't write about calling of Loaded event, it doesn't interest me. The problem is when I **attach** any handler to the Loaded event of the hidden button2 (just write in the VS designer 'Loaded="my_handler"'), the **IsLoaded** property is automatically set to true even if it should be set to false (because button2 is on the non activated tab).

Comment: `IsLoaded` is true after an element has been loaded, i.e. after the `Loaded` event was raised.

Comment: Please see the edit in the first post. I still don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: As i wrote: WPF is free to load (i.e. set `IsLoaded = true` and raise the `Loaded` event) *at any time* after an element is initialized, but before it is rendered. It might well decide to *immediately* load an element that has an event handler attached, and *delay* loading of an element without such a handler.

Comment: Ok, it seems I get it now. I thought that the Loaded event is raised **right** before the final rendering but it can be earlier, I misunderstood this part. I'm using it to make a decision if the control was rendered or if I have to render it in memory. In this case, IsLoaded is True but it wasn't rendered yet. It seems I will have to find another way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

do not use the default wpf logics;
from your handler, by starting using property arrays,
you could list from the handler your custom event setup;