# Get visible controls of new selected TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

In my `TabControl` `OnSelectionChanged` event I'm removing adorners from the previous selected tabpage and adding adorners to the new selected tabpage.

```
private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabControl = (TabControl)sender;
        var previousTabItem = (TabItem)e.RemovedItems[0];
        var newTabItem = (TabItem)e.AddedItems[0];

        RemoveTabItemsControlsAdorners(tabControl, previousTabItem);

        var tabControlChildrenSelected = TabControlHelper.GetTabControlAnalysisElements(UIHelper.FindVisualChildrenOfMultipleTypes(UIHelper.AnalysisControlTypes, tabControl.FindChildContentPresenter(newTabItem)));
        var details = (InputControlEventDetails)(tabControl).Tag;

        tabControlChildrenSelected = tabControlChildrenSelected.Concat(new[] { newTabItem });

        AddAdorners(tabControlChildrenSelected, details.InputControlEvents, details.NumberOfLoggedViews);
    }
```

This line gives me the elements of the new selected TabItem (it's not empty):

```
 var tabControlChildrenSelected = TabControlHelper.GetTabControlAnalysisElements(UIHelper.FindVisualChildrenOfMultipleTypes(UIHelper.AnalysisControlTypes, tabControl.FindChildContentPresenter(newTabItem)));
```

In my TabControlHelper I filter on visible elements. But all elements of the new selected TabItem aren't visible yet. So `GetTabControlAnalysisElements()` returns an empty collection. So I tried checking the visibilty by reflection but `methodInfo` is always null.

```
public static IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetTabControlAnalysisElements(IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> elements)
    {
        var visibleElements = elements.Where(element => WouldBeVisible(element));
        return visibleElements;
    }

    public static bool WouldBeVisible(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        // Returns true if the control would be visible if container is visible
        var methodInfo = element.GetType().GetMethod("GetState", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (methodInfo == null) return element.IsVisible;
        return (bool)(methodInfo.Invoke(element, new object[] { 2 }));
    }
```

How can I get the visible items of my new selected TabItem?

Comment: You'd be much better off doing that stuff with style or template triggers, for exactly this reason. But if you really want to do it the hard way, you need to find an event that is raised *after* the state you care about is initialized. [Maybe `TabItem.Loaded`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10714304/424129) or something. [This guy seems to be limping along with `GotFocus`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13469615/424129). If all else fails, maybe even grab a notification when the `Visibility` dependency property on the `TabItem` itself changes.

Comment: @EdPlunkett How would I use the TabItem.Loaded event?

Comment: Subscribe to it with an event handler. In the handler, call a method that does whatever you want to do when the tab item is loaded. If you're asking me how to set up the event handlers, I have no idea how you're creating the tab items, so I can't really say. Probably give the TabControl an ItemContainerStyle with an `EventSetter`, or in TabControl.Resources define a default TabItem style. If you're creating them in codebehind, `newTabItem.Loaded += TabItem_Loaded;`